# Reload VM in Vagrant script

Tags: bash, unix, debian, vagrant, locale

**Introduction**
I'm using Vagrant and want to create a box that fits my needs. I'm currently building my provisioning script but I have a problem which would require me to relog into the box.

**What I'm trying to achieve**
I want to set my locales to the German language

**What I'm doing**
After logging into my vagrant box with `vagrant ssh` I'm running the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo cp /var/www/projectfantasy/www/vagrant_ressources/locale.gen /etc/
sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
```

These steps are done with the help of [Debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Manually). The last step is

> To use the new settings with your programs, log out and back in.

And now I am where I need help. How would I relog while being in the vagrant provisioning script? When I don't relog I'm getting the following *warnings* when installing extra packages.

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

I mean, these are only warnings so that shouldn't be a problem, right? But I don't want to have warnings and would like to know how I could fix this issue.

When I relog and try to install those packages again it works without any problems.

Comment: have you already tried to just start a new bash session? `/bin/bash` EDIT: when thinking about it a doubt that this will work ;)

Comment: maybe by setting the [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) by hand?

Comment: Hm, I could try that. I'll give you a response tonight

Comment: Hey @dahrens - Sadly not working. When typing in `LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8` I'm getting the same error as before, and for the variables like `LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8` I'm getting the error message: `-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (de_DE.UTF-8): No such file or directory`

Comment: Could you simply log in again to localhost?  `ssh localhost` should provide a login shell, and you can perhaps `cat ~/.ssh/*.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to make it passwordless.  (If this works, I'll make it an answer for you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately, this is not so simple - if you issue a `reboot` command or `shutdown -r now` in your provisioning script the VM will restart (indeed) but then the provisioning will not continue.

fortunately, some people wrote plugin (https://github.com/exratione/vagrant-provision-reboot and https://github.com/aidanns/vagrant-reload) I experienced with the second and it works

make sure to install the plugin

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-reload
```

in your vagrantfile, your provisioning will look like

```
 config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant_ressources/preparations.sh"
 config.vm.provision :reload
 config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant_ressources/bootstrap.sh"
```

so preparations.sh will execute, then the VM will reload and bootstrap.sh will execute

in your preparations.sh, after you generate locale, make sure variables are set in the locale file :

```
sudo locale-gen 
echo -e 'LANG=de_DE.UTF-8\nLC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8' > /etc/default/locale
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Berlin
```

PS : one note on your usage of the shell provisioning. By default provisioning is run with root privilege so there is no need for all the `sudo` ; if you want to run the provisioning as vagrant user run it as `config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false ...` and you will need the sudo

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. This does indeed restart my box, however does not fix my problems. Even after restarting I'm getting the same errors. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: not sure, can you elaborate on the next steps of your provisioning so it can be reproduce

Comment: Here you got my files: https://gist.github.com/tzfrs/373e8c80de123f099265ef536484aeae

I added all files that are used by this script

Comment: ok hard to check as your project files are missing .. I would suggest to add in the `/etc/default/locale`

Comment: Hey. Sorry, had to remove my comment, since it didn't fix the problem. I now added the `echo` of your post and am checking it again

Comment: Thanks! The part with `echo` made it work now. Seems like my `/etc/default/locale` was just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your warning, but I find this will allow you to set LC_ALL:

```
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
```

(from https://askubuntu.com/questions/114759/warning-setlocale-lc-all-cannot-change-locale, but works for debian jessie as well)